# How to view attempts for IIS blocked IP

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-10, windows-server-2016

How does one block IP address from accessing a web app in IIS (V10). And also, how can I view, the many times, the IP address tried to access the web app, or how can I set the IIS to log these attempts (including time, the payload etc)? Thanks for your help.

Comment: found a way to block the IP address: https://www.ntweekly.com/2017/07/21/block-specific-ip-address-from-accessing-iis-10-web-site/

Comment: This is not a place to ask for tutorials, but Microsoft Docs has several articles on how to block/allow specific IP addresses or dynamically, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/using-dynamic-ip-restrictions IIS by default writes the attempts in IIS log files with specific status/substatus codes.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Dynamic IP Restrictions** to block the IP addresses of HTTP clients that make unusually large numbers of concurrent requests or that make large numbers of requests in a short period of time.

Use **IP Address and Domain Restrictions** can block specific IP addresses.

But there is no direct log file dedicated to this kind of operation to record the time when the IP was blocked and the payload, etc.